# Policy file in JAR package

Tags: java, jar, rmi, policy

Is there possibility to read .policy file from JAR package? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507994/jar-policy-file) question but link here is broken, i tried to use code like below but it not works, and I've got exception (exception message below code). I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163090/security-policy-files-and-jar?rq=1), with same result

java.policy

```
grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

TelnetServer.java

```
package telnetserver;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class TelnetServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RmiServer{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TelnetServer() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TelnetServer ts = new TelnetServer();
            String plik =  ts.getClass().getResource("java.policy").getFile();
            System.out.println(plik);
            System.setProperty("java.security.policy",plik);
            System.setSecurityManager(new java.rmi.RMISecurityManager());
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1087);
            Naming.rebind("//localhost:1087/TelnetServer", new TelnetServer());
            System.err.println("Serwer działa!");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Złapano wyjątek: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public String execute(String login, String haslo, String cmd) throws RemoteException {
        return "Działa";
    }

}
```

Exception

> run:
>   /C:/Users/User/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TelnetServer/build/classes/telnetserver/java.policy
>   Złapano wyjątek: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1087" "listen,resolve")
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1087" "listen,resolve")   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1131)
>     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)    at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:128)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:345)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:330)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234)
>     at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:195)   at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.(RegistryImpl.java:180)   at
>   java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:203)
>     at telnetserver.TelnetServer.main(TelnetServer.java:32)

Comment: Well you haven't told Java that it's *in* the JAR. You removed all that information when you called `getFile()`.

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: Err, don't remove all that information by calling `getFile()`?